# Need help with defining a subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you define the definition of a subsequence of $x_n$ if $x_n$
is an integer?

By definition it increasing subset of natural numbers from $x_n$
For instance let $x_n=(c,c,c..)$
Any subset of this sequence the elements are constant when 
$k_1$<…<$k_n$

So I was thinking if the elements are constant,does that infer
that the indices should be equal 
That is what I was trying to say.

(I hope I got my point through)

Comment: Think of a sequence as a function $f$ with domain $S$ where $S$ is an infinite subset of $ \Bbb N$ (or of $\Bbb N\cup \{0\}$) and a sub-sequence of $f$ as the restriction of $f $ to a domain $T$ where $T$  is an infinite subset of $S.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence. Then a *subsequence* of $(x_n)$ is a sequence $(x_{k_n})$, where $k_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers.

I think you’re getting confused between the index of the sequence and the value of the sequence itself. The definition you have been given is saying the equivalent of what I have said above—that $k_1 < k_2 < \dots$ or that the sequence of *indices* to the sequence is strictly increasing. It doesn’t say that the *value* of the sequence is strictly increasing.

Comment: I don{t think this is what was asked...

Comment: @DonAntonio I’m a bit confused about what is being asked, then.. I’ll take this answer down if it is of no help.

Comment: Well, trying to make some sense from what is written in the question, I think the OP is trying to ask the following: if $\;\{x_n\}\subset\Bbb Z\;$ is a sequence s.t. $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=c\in\Bbb R\;$ , then there exists $\;M\in\Bbb N\;$ such that for any $\;n\ge M\;$ the sequence $\;\{x_n\}\;$ is *constant* (and, in fact, equal to the limit $\;c\;$ ) . The OP messes up with subsequences as the question  may have been given that way, but it is just the same, since any subsequence of a converging sequence converges and\ to the same limit.

Comment: So the indices are strictly increasing. So if sequence consists of an integer,then it must be constant since lim K=K?

Comment: Thanks I guess I got confused. DonAntonio got it right as the first person. I thought the values related to the indices and thier ordering

Comment: @雨が好きな人 .In General Topology by R. Engelking, he uses $\{x_n\}$ to denote a sequence.  In that notation, we have a function $f$ with domain $\Bbb N$ but we write $x_n$ for $f(n)$.....   I think this answer  is exactly right.